# My program is not respond on time to the output variation of sensor

Tags: pi-3

I am using radar sensor connect with my raspberry pi3. Radar gives a series of data. My code detects that series of input and display a particular number of data and display on lcd after that using that data and comparing it with previous data it makes led on and off. Here i am making led on for 10sec when detected present output is less or greater than previous output by + or - 2.

Here when a number of objects increases or decreases serial data input of raspberry pi increases and decreases simultaneously.

Led and display does not respond to the actual input data object variation as time goes on.And in the end it respond very very late.

Help me in correct my mistake and provide me a solution for this to solve my issue.

Lcd code i have entered in while loop to print object number of objects on lcd at

```
if flag==4 and count==28:
        ser.write(rbuff)
        lcd_string(str(rbuff),LCD_LINE_2,2)
        count=0
        flag=0
```

When i am removing either which makes led on for 10sec or this lcd_string command of above code. Code is responding on time. 
Thank you in advance.

```
if flag==4 and count==28:
        ser.write(rbuff)
        lcd_string(str(rbuff),LCD_LINE_2,2)
        count=0
        flag=0

        if (rbuff[0]-2 <= temp) and  (temp<= rbuff[0]+2):
            GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
            ser.write(rbuff)
            #start=0
            temp=rbuff[0]
            print(GPIO.input(18))


        else:
            GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
            #start=0
            start=10+(time.time())
            #print(start)
            temp=rbuff[0]
            print(start)
            #print("ON")

        if start==0:
            GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

        else:
            GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
            now=time.time()
            seconds=start-now
            #print(seconds)
            if seconds>0:
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
                #print("on")
            else:
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
                #print("off1")
                start=0
```

Comment: (1) I assume your radar is connected to Rpi using uart.  Please correct me if have made a wrong guess.  (2) radar tells Rpi something like this: yes another space ship, yes one again, one again.  (3) rpi counts number of spaceships for 10 seconds and switch on alarm LED if more space ships are detected.  (4) So your space ship alarm system has two components (a) radar and uart output component (b) rpi + uart + spaceships counting and comparison and switch on alert LED.  Please let us know if part (a) is fully tested.  If yes, we can move on checking out part (b).

Comment: There is no point posting code snippets and asking why it is slow.  You need to post the complete program.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.Yes you are right radar connected with rpi using uart.But here bunch of data transmitted from radar with fix starting byte 02 01 04 03... 08 if rpi detects this data it counts that byte and print data at which count=28 which shows total number of object. this process repeats every time and find total number of objects. Here in rpi first total number of objects is taken in temp variable and then compare it with next total number of objects which is coming every time in rbuff so by using if condition i compare it with rbuff+2 and rbuff-2 value with temp. Here led must be on for 10sec in background process of comparing rbuff with temp must be continue and after 10s if this condition again detects temp object is less than or greater than by 2 again led on for 10s and so on.if coming data is greater than or less than 2 by previous data which i am taking in temp.

I display that data on lcd at count=28 and then this data process for above procedure of making led on for 10s and then off.And yes part(a)led on procedure for 10s is tested and it works fine but when i add lcd part it becomes very slow and as time goes on it becomes very very slow. At a time either of display or led on for 10s part works well but when i mix both this part it becomes slow and slow as time goes on.

Here i am posting my complete code.In question i posted a post at which my code has an issue.Here i am not find my code posted in proper condition in preview.If that is so tell me how do i post my code so you can get it in proper condition.

```
import threading
import queue
import serial
import time 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

LCD_RS = 23
LCD_E  = 24
LCD_D4 = 12
LCD_D5 = 16
LCD_D6 = 20
LCD_D7 = 21


LCD_WIDTH = 20    
LCD_CHR = True
LCD_CMD = False

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94 # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4 # LCD RAM address for the 4th line

E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

count_enable=0
count=0
flag=0
transmit_flag=0
rbuff=list(range(100))
temp=0
temp1=0
print("staring program")
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',921600,timeout=1)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

events_queue = queue.Queue()

def lcd():

   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
   GPIO.setwarnings(False)
   GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  # E
   GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) # DB4
   GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) # DB5
   GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) # DB6
   GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) # D7


   lcd_init()

def lcd_init():

   lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD) # 110011 Initialise
   lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD) # 110010 Initialise
   lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD) # 000110 Cursor move direction
   lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD) # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off
   lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD) # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
   lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD) # 000001 Clear display
   time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):

   GPIO.output(LCD_RS, mode) # RS
   GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
   if bits&0x10==0x10:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
   if bits&0x20==0x20:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
   if bits&0x40==0x40:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
   if bits&0x80==0x80:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

   lcd_toggle_enable()

   GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
   GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
   if bits&0x01==0x01:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
   if bits&0x02==0x02:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
   if bits&0x04==0x04:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
   if bits&0x08==0x08:
       GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

   lcd_toggle_enable()

def lcd_toggle_enable():

   time.sleep(E_DELAY)
   GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)
   time.sleep(E_PULSE)
   GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)
   time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line,style):

   if style==1:
       message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")
   if style==2:
       message = message.center(LCD_WIDTH," ")
   elif style==3:
       message = message.rjust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

   lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

   for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
       lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_backlight(flag):

   GPIO.output(LED_ON, flag)

def thread_read():
   global count_enable, flag,temp, count,start2,start
   start=0
   lcd()
   while True:
       rbuff=ser.read()
       if count_enable == 1:
           count+=1
       if rbuff[0] == 0x02 and flag==0: # and zero_detect==1: 
           count_enable=1
           flag=1
       if rbuff[0] == 0x01 and flag==1  and count==1:
           flag=2
       if rbuff[0] == 0x04 and flag==2 and count==2:
           flag=3
       if rbuff[0] == 0x03 and flag==3 and count==3:
           flag=4

       if flag==4 and count==28:
           ser.write(rbuff)
           lcd_string(str(rbuff),LCD_LINE_2,2)
           count=0
           flag=0

           if (rbuff[0]-2 <= temp) and  (temp<= rbuff[0]+2):
               GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
               ser.write(rbuff)
               temp=rbuff[0]
               print(GPIO.input(18))


           else:
               GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
               start=10+(time.time())
               temp=rbuff[0]
               print(start)

           if start==0:
               GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

           else:
               GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
               now=time.time()
               seconds=start-now
               if seconds>0:
                   GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
               else:
                   GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
                   start=0

       if count == 1 and rbuff[0] != 0x01:
           count_enable=0
           count=0
           flag=0

read_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_read)
read_thread.start()

event=threading.Event()
try:    
   event.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.